# Change rect destination in XNA

Tags: graphics, xna

hy guys, im newbie and im confused with XNA rectangle

I draw something and rotate it, but the rectangle destination its still same, how to change the destination rectangle so i can check the collision with intersect method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rotate a Rectangle.

Instead, what you want to do is a Bounding Box.  It will not provide you with pixel perfect collision, but it will provide you with a quick intersect check that could be paired with a more refined collision check.

Refer to this question on how to create a Bounding Box:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2438/how-do-i-create-bounding-boxes-with-xna-4-0